Garry's Mod - How do I attach VGUI to entities?
How can I attach VGUI to entities?
I know how to create VGUI's and I know how to render stuff with Start3D2D but I really don't know how to use VGUI on entities. I have seen some paid addons in which for example money printers have a cursors and a menu. I believe it was made with VGUI.
